# Item is not being found in dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have this condition in an if statement:

```
If myDict.Exists(Cells(d.Row, d.Column - 1)) Then
```

At a particular step in the code (while stepping through it),  the following code in the Immediate window

```
MsgBox Cells(d.Row,d.Column-1)
```

gives me a value of "1/3/2011"

And at that very step,

```
MsgBox myDict.Item("1/3/2011")
```

returns a value too.

However, my if condition posted above does not equate to true. Why??

Do I need to be casting the result of Cells(d.Row,d.Column-1) as a certain type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells returns an object. I usually just cast the cell into a range:
((XL.Range)Cells(d.Row,d.Column-1)).Value2.ToString().
Then compare the strings.

Comment: Thanks. I found a workaround that didn't require me to use a dictionary, but thanks for the solution should I ever need it in future.